# The button is still active even when I remove the cursor from it, ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, game-development

Ok so I have my game but i have a issue that whenever I press the button, while the button is still being pressed if i remove my cursor from it without releasing the mouse button it the button is still active. How can I resolve it to make it that whenever the mouse is not in the button's hit zone it is not active----to explain it better and simple..If I press the button adn dont let go of it and if I were to drag the mouse off the buttons zone and let go the button will still be active, how can I resolve that?. Here is my code that make the player walk.

```
    var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;

var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var shootDown:Boolean = false;

var onGround:Boolean = true;


var level:Number = 1;

var bullets:Array = new Array();
var container_mc:MovieClip; 
var enemies:Array = new Array();

var score:Number = 0;

var tempEnemy:MovieClip;

var tempLaser:MovieClip;

var timesHit:uint = 0;

// BUTTON EVENTS EITHER CLICKED OR NOT

left_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, moveLeft);
right_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, moveRight);
up_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, moveUp);
shoot_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, shootPressed);

left_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, leftUp);
right_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, rightUp);
up_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, upUp);


player.gotoAndStop('still');


stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenter);

function onenter(e:Event):void{
    if (rightPressed == true && leftPressed == false){
        player.x += 8;
        player.scaleX = 1;
        player.gotoAndStop("walking");
        cloud.x -= 8;


    } else if (leftPressed == true && rightPressed == false){
        player.x -= 8;
        player.scaleX = -1;
        player.gotoAndStop('walking');
        cloud.x += 8;

   } else if(upPressed == true && leftPressed == false && rightPressed == false){


       }
        else{  
        rightPressed = false;
        leftPressed = false;
        player.gotoAndStop('still')}

}
// **** MOVEMENT CONTROLS *********



function shootPressed(e:MouseEvent):void{
    shootDown = true;
    if(shootDown == true){
        fireBullet();
        }

    }


function fireBullet():void
{
    var playerDirection:String;
    if(player.scaleX < 0){
        playerDirection = "left";
    } else if(player.scaleX > 0){
        playerDirection = "right";
    }
    var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(player.x, player.y, playerDirection);
    //bullets = new Array();
    bullet.y = player.y + 8;
    stage.addChild(bullet);
    bullets.push(bullet);
    trace(bullets);

}

// BUTTON FUNCTIONS

function moveLeft(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN){
    leftPressed = true;
    }else if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP) {
        leftPressed = false;
        }

}
function moveRight(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN){
    rightPressed = true;
    }else if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP){
        rightPressed = false;
        }

}

function moveUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN){
        upPressed = true;
        onGround = false;
        player.y -= 100;
        } 



}



function leftUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    leftPressed = false;
}
function rightUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    rightPressed = false;
}
function upUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    upPressed = false;
 if(upPressed == false){
     player.y += 100;

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, I think, what you were looking for. That should be enough.

```
left_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, moveLeft);
left_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, LeftUp);

function moveLeft(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  leftPressed = true;
  left_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, LeftOut);
}

function leftUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  leftPressed = false;
  left_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, LeftOut);
}

function leftOut(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  leftPressed = false;
  left_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, LeftOut);
}
```

MOUSE_OUT simply trigger when the mouse is out of your Object so you only have to add an EventListener with this type of Event. Of course, you may understand that it's not that smart to listen to this event if you didn't clicked on your btn before, that's why I choose to add the MOUSE_OUT only when MOUSE_DOWN is listened. 
Since what you want is only to set leftPressed when you Up your mouse I guess that you want the same for when your mouse is out. 
After this, I remove useless listeners (MOUSE_OUT) to be able to listen to them again and because it's a common waste of memory.

But, I really can't understand why you do :

```
function moveLeft(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   if(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN){
       leftPressed = true;
   }else if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP) {
       leftPressed = false;
   }
}
```

What is the use of that ?!

Comment: Hey i tried to copy and paste the function but it give me the error that it expects 2 parameters?.. because I didi this '
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseOut);

function onMouseOut():void {
removeEventListener(moveLeft);
}'       and it didnt work.!

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you could understand and I should have read more your code. There are many things to say about your code (about optimization and logical construction) and I'm not sure to understand everything you wrote in your code but I'll edit my post and give you what you want. (well - i'll try)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that im new to ActionScript, the code works but im still having the same issue for some reason. Im thinking if there is some way I can do the enter frame listener to check for the mouse's position every frame..Dont know if that could work?.

Comment: hey lol I didnt scroll down the page and read the rest of your responce. but on the moveLeft I tried to make it so if the button was clicked leftPressed would be true and if it was released it would be false..?

Comment: hey actually sorry I just went fully tard lol it works!! thank you so much now Im going to study that code lol.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the mouseup event you need to do something with the mouse out event.
If you don't, the mouse up event is never triggered when the cursor moves from the button while the mouse is down ("drag out").

use the event `MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT` or `MouseEvent.RELEASE_OUTSIDE`

The best way is to add eventlisteners to the `MOUSE_UP` event and either the `MOUSE_OUT` or `RELEASE_OUTSIDE` when the `MOUSE_DOWN` event is triggered.

Code example:

```
left_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleButtonDown);


function handleButtonDown(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
   // activate "up" listeners
   e.target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleButtonUp);
   e.target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, handleButtonUp);
   e.target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RELEASE_OUTSIDE, handleButtonUp);

   // call your button action function
   // e.target is your button
   buttonDownAction(e.target);

}


function handleButtonUp(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
   // activate "up" listeners
   e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleButtonUp);
   e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, handleButtonUp);
   e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.RELEASE_OUTSIDE, handleButtonUp);

   // call your button action function
   // e.target is your button
   buttonUpAction(e.target);

}

function buttonDownAction(button:MovieClip) {
   switch(button) {
      case left_btn: 
          // do your thing here

      case right_btn:
          // do something else here
    }
}
```

in this example I made the handleButtonDown and handleButtonUp a bit more generic so you can use these 2 functions for all your buttons.

Hope it helps you, good luck!

Comment: Hey thank you for answering and I kind of understand how you would apply it but do you mind giving me a example using one of my functions?.

Comment: a really easy way, if its not a big project just add a mouse move function to detect onOver , mouseOut, proberly bad practice but everytime the mouse moves it will check, simple and effective